# How to select only those rows which have more than one of given fields with values

Tags: sql, mysql, select

Is there some elegant way to do that, **without** a big `WHERE` with lots of `AND` and `OR`? For example there are 4 columns: A, B, C, D. For each row the columns have random integer values. I need to select only those rows which have more than one column with a non-zero value. For example (1,2,3,4) and (3,4,0,0) should get selected, however (0,0,7,0) should not be selected (there are no rows that have zeros only).

PS. I know how this looks but the funny thing is that this is not exam or something, it's a real query which I need to use in a real app :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There. No `WHERE`, no `OR` and no `AND`:

```
SELECT
   IF(`column1` != 0,1,0) +
   IF(`column2` != 0,1,0) +
   IF(`column3` != 0,1,0) +
   IF(`column4` != 0,1,0) AS `results_sum`
FROM `table`
HAVING
   `results_sum` > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   (0, 0, 0) NOT IN ((a, b, c), (a, b, d), (a, c, d), (b, c, d))
```

This I believe is this shortest way, though not necessarily the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select *
from table t
where ( abs(sign(A))
      + abs(sign(B))
      + abs(sign(C))
      + abs(sign(D))
      ) > 0
```